# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 Not Returning Search Results Except For Site Collection Administrators

Tags: windows, permissions, sharepoint

We have a recent Sharepoint Foundation 2010 installation that is working fine except for searching. When you search as a site collection administrator, everything works perfectly and results are returned as expected. When you search as anyone else, be it a visitor with limited access or a site administrator, it returns no results.

There aren't any errors in the event log and Sharepoint seems to think its doing what I want it to do, but I can't seem to find any permissions anywhere that might be causing this issue.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by something going foobar during the upgrade process from sharepoint services 3.0 to foundation 2010. No matter what we did we couldn't fix the issue, so we set up foundation 2010 elsewhere, imported the data, and had absolutely no issues after that. We billed a couple of hours of a sharepoint specialist's time to make sure we were correct before migrating everything and he confirmed that the only fix was to blow away the sharepoint install and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that all permissions to reading the documentation have been given to more than just the site collection administrators?